# RxJava How to return more than 2 ArrayLists within Observable in a function

Tags: android, observable, rx-java

I'm able to pass two lists via observable as it is mentioned below

```
fun loadAll(contact: String?): Single<Pair<ArrayList<Contact>, ArrayList<Contact>>> {
    return packageDB.loadAll()
        .map { table ->
            val one = ArrayList< Contact >()
            val two = ArrayList< Contact >()
            val three = ArrayList< Contact >()
            
            one to two
        }
}
```

And in Fragment, I'm trying to return as:

```
  disposables.add(
        viewModel.loadAll(contact)
            .subscribe({
                val firstList = it.first
                val secondList = it.second
                val third = ArrayList<Contact>()
 }))
```

I'm new to reactive programming so I'm unable to understand how I can pass or return more than two lists as Pair object can have two child objects only. I would be thankful if you can let me know the solution.

Comment: Can you not just create a class to hold whatever you want and return that instead?

Comment: Agree with @IvanWooll. Create a class that holds whichever data you want and use it in Single<YourClass>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way of doing this, I can list some. You simply have to think of the return object. If you want to return 3 things only, I wouldn't even bother with creating a specific class if it's clear what you're doing. Kotlin has already a class for this - [Triple](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-triple/). It's like a pair, but holds 3 values:

```
fun loadAll(contact: String?): Single<Triple<ArrayList<Contact>, ArrayList<Contact>, ArrayList<Contact>>> {
    return packageDB.loadAll()
        .map { table ->
            val one = ArrayList< Contact >()
            val two = ArrayList< Contact >()
            val three = ArrayList< Contact >()
            
            Triple(one, two, three)
        }
}
```

And then access them as:

```
disposables.add(
        viewModel.loadAll(contact)
            .subscribe({
                val firstList = it.first
                val secondList = it.second
                val third = it.third
 }))
```

---

If you have more than 3 values, I'm not sure if there's already a class for this, but there's always the option of using arrays of arrays:

```
fun loadAll(contact: String?): Single<Array<ArrayList<Contact>> {
    return packageDB.loadAll()
        .map { table ->
            val one = ArrayList< Contact >()
            val two = ArrayList< Contact >()
            val three = ArrayList< Contact >()
            
            arrayListOf(one, two, three)
        }
} 


disposables.add(
        viewModel.loadAll(contact)
            .subscribe({ (firList, secondList, thirdList) ->
                  // the above destructures the list into 3 variables
                  // if the list has less than 3 elements you'll get an index out of bounds exception
                  // otherwise you can just use the variables
 }))
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, this might create some problems understanding what each value is, so sometimes it's better to create your own class:

```
data class Values(
   val primaryContacts: ArrayList< Contact >(),
   val secondaryContacts: ArrayList< Contact >(),
   val emergencyContacts: ArrayList< Contact >(),
)

fun loadAll(contact: String?): Single<Values> {
    return packageDB.loadAll()
        .map { table ->
            val one = ArrayList< Contact >()
            val two = ArrayList< Contact >()
            val three = ArrayList< Contact >()
            
            Values(one, two, three)
        }
} 

disposables.add(
        viewModel.loadAll(contact)
            .subscribe({
                val firstList = it.primaryContacts
                val secondList = it.secondaryContacts
                val third = it.emergencyContacts
 }))
```

*please excuse the naming. It's just an example.*

Comment: Thanks man. I also solved it like this yesterday. Sorry I'm new in Rx so taking time to understand.

Comment: No need for apologies. We've all been there and some of us before StackOverflow :D